# Amcharts json, no chart

Tags: json, amcharts

my php-generated Json file looks like this:

```
 [ { "category": "2015-07-02 20:13:58", "value1": 30.500, "value2": 30.500 }, { "category": "2015-07-02 20:14:59", "value1": 29.750, "value2": 29.750 }, { "category": "2015-07-02 20:16:01", "value1": 29.125, "value2": 29.125 }, { "category": "2015-07-02 20:17:03", "value1": 28.625, "value2": 28.625 }, { "category": "2015-07-02 20:18:04", "value1": 28.125, "value2": 28.125 } ]
```

And my amcharts file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>amCharts tutorial: Loading external data</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- prerequisites -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/style.css"  
type="text/css">
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"    
type="text/javascript"> 
</script>

<!-- cutom functions -->
<script>
AmCharts.loadJSON = function(url) {
// create the request
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
// code for IE6, IE5
var request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}

// load it
// the last "false" parameter ensures that our code will wait before the
// data is loaded
request.open('GET', url, true);
request.send();

// parse adn return the output
return eval(request.responseText);
};
</script>

<!-- chart container -->
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;"></div>

<!-- the chart code -->
<script>
var chart;

 // create chart
 AmCharts.ready(function() {

// load the data
var chartData = AmCharts.loadJSON('data.php');

// SERIAL CHART
chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
chart.pathToImages = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/images/";
chart.dataProvider = chartData;
chart.categoryField = "category";
chart.dataDateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS";

// GRAPHS

var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph1.valueField = "value1";
graph1.bullet = "round";
graph1.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
graph1.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
graph1.lineThickness = 2;
graph1.lineAlpha = 0.5;
chart.addGraph(graph1);

var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
graph2.valueField = "value2";
graph2.bullet = "round";
graph2.bulletBorderColor = "#FFFFFF";
graph2.bulletBorderThickness = 2;
graph2.lineThickness = 2;
graph2.lineAlpha = 0.5;
chart.addGraph(graph2);

// CATEGORY AXIS
chart.categoryAxis.parseDates = true;

// WRITE
chart.write("chartdiv");
});

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunatly i get no chart, see here: http://bitfreun.de/index.html
I just can see a message in chrome developer console:
"Exception in onResRdy: TypeError: Cannot read property 'htmlRes' of undefined"

Comment: Can you post the code to your data.php file as well? There seems to something wrong with your data, i.e strange symbols between the values and the commas, which causes JSON parser to fail, hence no chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found mistake in first row,i mean in your **JSON format**,
as per my experience you can not use `":"` in your resulting string,
for Eg,

```
2015-07-02 20:13:58
```

Here when you put **`20:13:58`** at that time it can not be recognized by the dataprovider,so what to do with it,Try to remove `:` from this JSON string,this should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your request.
When you open it, you set async to true. This causes the 'loadJSON' function to return `undefined`, because the response has not returned when you ask for `request.responseText`.
The result is, that the `dataProvider`of your chart is `undefined`and therefore your chart does not work.
To solve this either use
`request.open('GET', url, FALSE);`
Or use `onreadystatechange` for the response and then redraw the chart.

Comment: Well in fact it was the problem. But now your JSON requested seems like to be NOT structured like the example you gave above. You only have "value" fields but neither "value1" nor "value2" as requested by the chart.

Comment: And i would recommend you to use the onreadystatechange event for the request. Because if the request won't return immediately, it will freeze your page.